# automatically fill in field value when user sign up wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to automatically assign a random phone number to new user's phone field when someone register on my wordpress website.

The reason is that I do not want to collect unnecessary data from my customers but my payment gateway requires my customer's phone number. I personally don't like to put in my numbers when I buy things and I don't want that in my website either.

So, if some value is automatically assigned during the sign up and not shown to the users, it would fool my payment gateway.

Tried this in functions.php. Didn't work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer','save_phone');

    function save_phone($customer_id) {
        $phoneno = '000000000';
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', $phoneno);
    }
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: perhaps you may use custom registration form plugin (there are a lot, google it) and create a hidden field there which will generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your payment gateway requires a phone number, then you must capture a phone number - this is possibly used to validate the payment. Payment providers use postcode and phone number to validate the card information and as an anti fraud measure.

Comment: No. The payment gateway does not use phone number to validate any payment. It's just an unnecessary info which I don't want to collect from my customer.

Comment: Just use a hidden form field and set the value of the default value to '0123456789' or similar :)